# Rotation of an anisotropic inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces, vectors

Consider the following function $$\sum_{i=1}^3{ \frac{(q_i-d_i)^2}{a_i} },$$
which can be seen as an anisotropic inner product in the $\vec{q}$ vector space that is rescaled by $a_i$’s and offset by $\vec{d}$. In general, constant $a_i$’s are nonzero and unequal. $\vec{d}$ is a constant vector in $\vec q$ space.

My question is the following. Can one rotate in the $\vec{q}$ space and thus express the above function in some new $\tilde{q}_i,\tilde{d}_i$ in order to have only one nonzero $\tilde{d}_i$ for $i=1,2,3$ (i.e., align new $\tilde{\vec d}$ along one axis)?

Comment: So the $\vec{a}$ is fixed and this is a function of $\vec{q}$ and $\vec{d}$ in some $3$-dimensional space?

Comment: @Dave Yes. Clarified now in the post.